# The tangent space at a point p is isomorphic to the space of derivation at a point p.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am currently reading Loring Tu differential geometry. There is something I want to understand in the proof for the statement below:

The linear map $\phi : T_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow D_{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

So I can follow all of the statement of the proof, but there is something I am very confused about. When we show surjectivity we pick a arbitrarily derivation $D \in D_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and we want to see how it works on germ $(f,V)$. We found that $Df(x) = \Sigma \ (Dx^i) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$.

This is only for a specific x in the domain. So why is it true for the v that we choose below it works for every single x ? Is there something I am missing ?

[image]

Comment: What was special about the chosen $x$? The above argument would work regardless of which $x$ you choose. At each $x$ the Taylor's theorem would apply, so that would only change $g_i(x)$. This argument works because $x$ is "arbitrary".

Comment: This is what I am confused about. So,  here only one v should determine D right ? I mean if we have different x choosen, then that would give different D ? Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Here is the issue I am confused about so for example getting the same f. Then for $y \neq x$ we have $Df(y) = \Sigma (Dy^i) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i}(p)$ which isn't the same as $D_vf(y)$ no ? Maybe my confusion is with the definitions ? I am not sure.

Comment: A change of coordinate charts does not affect the value. the structure of the tangent space helps avoid this situation. I will think about it, and then try to write a clear answer.

Comment: I was right. So the thing is, you are trying to change the coordinates from $x_i$ to $y_i$, that's why you are getting two apparently different sums $\sum (Dx_i)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p)$, and $\sum (Dy_i)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}(p)$.Using the chain rule, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial  f}{\partial y_i}$ are related. Furthermore, this relation is then quotiented out in the  definition of the tangent space at a point.  The definition of the tangent space will make you understand why a change of coordinate chart does not actually change the derivation.

Comment: Why is that? Can you please add an answer with the details? I am starting to understand, but not the total picture.

Comment: Okay,  I  will do so. But I may take some time.'

Comment: No problem, take all the time that you need no rush.

Comment: Let me clarify one last time : when you mean that "for the $v$ we choose below it works for every single $x$", do you mean $x$ as a point in $V$, or as the coordinate chart $(x^1,x^2,...,)$ on $V$? Forgive me, it is only that I do not want to write a wrong answer.

Comment: I mean x as a point of V ?